# What are some relevant statistic calculations?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, descriptive-statistics, psychology

I applied a test for attachment and 2 different tests for internet addiction to 114 highschool students. All tests have a Likert scale 1-5. My hypothesis is that the attachment and internet scales will have a negative correlation.
What are the relevant calculations that I need to perform, to include in a psychology bachelor final thesis?
I'm thinking about central tendencies, Pearson's r for correlation, a comparison between male and female subgroups, and this is where I get lost.
Would a regression test be useful? Or a standard distribution?
Could I estimate the tendencies in the population based on the sample?
I could really use some help here, as I need to submit my bachelor thesis in a few days, so thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated, Alex. You've asked quite a lot and so I'm not sure that you will get a lot of answers. Maybe ask separate questions with more specific topic questions in their titles.

Comment: When you ask a question, make sure that you have supplied all of the relevant information. For example, what is "attachment" and how is it measured? Does it have a Likert scale as well?

Comment: When evaluating the results of a study, the graphical display(s) of the data can often be more important than the statistical evaluation. A graphical display of the data in question also makes it easier for people to give relevant answers to your questions.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the answer and kind feedback.

Comment: I'll integrate your suggestions in future posts. Attachment is a psychological trait that I didn't want to explain, as I'm interested in the statistical, not the psychological approach. I can replace attachment with intelligence or extraversion, it wouldn't make any difference for me. Yes, it does have a Likert scale.